# Alternative to delay() when using Ticker in ESP8622

Tags: esp8266

When using the Ticker library on the ESP8266 you can't use the `delay()` function because Ticker functions are using the underlying timer. The [original Arduino library](https://github.com/sstaub/Ticker) says that you can use a Ticker as delay, but in the [ESP8266 implementation](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Ticker) things work differently. You "attach()" a callback function and specify the period.

**How can I generate a delay that doesn't require the underlying timer?**

(BTW, where is the documentation for the ESP8266 Ticker library? The [repository](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Ticker) has no documentation nor comments on the functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the ticker callback to increment a value. this value can be used as millis() substitute. actually the "millis" is made that way.

write a simple function to give you a delay. **this code assumes the callback function is interrupt/event driven like a systick timer in ARMs.**

```
uint32_t ticks;

void callbackFunc()
{
   ticks++;
}

void myDelay(uint32_t del)
{
   uint32_t tempTime = ticks;
   while (ticks < tempTime + del);
}
```

Comment: Yes. That seems to work, but I do need to put `ESP.wdtFeed();` inside the while loop in the delay function. Otherwise the watchdog timer is triggered.